# Using storyboard only for certain view controllers

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uistoryboard

I have done a separate project using storyboard.

I need to integrate with an existing big project which doesn't use storyboard.

Is it possible to use storyboard partly (only for some view controllers)? If so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can instantiate separate view controllers from storyboard:

Getting a Storyboard Object

```
+ storyboardWithName:bundle:
```

Instantiating Storyboard View Controllers

```
– instantiateInitialViewController
– instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
```

For ex:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *yourVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdentifier"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is possible.  Any view controllers that aren't on the storyboard are presented in exactly the same way they were in the old projected, by instantiating, setting properties (if need be), and pushing.